# How to check if a cookie exists even if it was created in another application? (using JS or C#)

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, cookies, httpcookie

I have several applications and one of them is a central application that manages authentication, and where a `LogOn` page is imported from as an `IFrame` to the other applications.

When the `userName` and `password` are correct, I create a cookie named `userInfo`.

Now, in the current app, I want to check if the cookie of `userInfo` exists. I think I should check it exists in the browser (in client side).

It must be possible, so how can I do it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you are wanting to implement single sign on. Do all the applications live on the same domain or use the same domain if accessed via a sub domain?

Comment: @DanLister Not all the applications are in the same domain. There must be a way to know it maybe through a url or something...

Comment: This sounds like an enormous security risk to me.  You do not WANT a cookie from one domain to be readable by any arbitrary other domain.

Comment: I agree with stephen.vakil. For multiple domain applications, you'll need a central application to manage authentication. Something like ADFS would do the trick.

Comment: @DanLister That's exactly what I have - a central application that manages authentication. I show the same Login page in the other applications. But I don't know how the current application has a way to know if the userName and password were good.

Comment: Maybe I need to check if a cookie named `UserInfo` exist in this browser, but anybody knows how to do that ??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cookies cannot be shared cross domain. If your applications are not hosted on the same domain you have to forget about this. It won't work because browsers (for obvious security reasons) do not send cookies cross domain. There are other ways to implement cross domain single sign on (see the second part of my answer).

Now let's suppose that your applications are on the same domain and you have multiple applications spread over different sub-domains of the root domain:

- login.foo.com
- app.foo.com
- xxx.foo.com

and you want to share authentication between those sub domains. All you have to do is specify set the `domain` property in your web.config to the root domain:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms
    loginUrl="https://login.foo.com"
    requireSSL="true"
    protection="All"
    timeout="120"
    domain="foo.com"
    slidingExpiration="false"
    name="sso" />
</authentication>
```

The same configuration should be applied to the `web.config` of all applications. And that's pretty much all you need to do. Once the user is authenticated on one of the sub domains he will automatically be authenticated on the others thanks to the fact that cookies can be shared cross sub domains.

---

If you want to achieve cross domain single sign on then you will have to take a different approach. You could use the same [machine keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx) between the different applications to encrypt the authentication token. Here are the steps:

1. User navigates to `https://foo.com` and is presented with a Logon screen because he is not authenticated on this domain yet.
2. The user authenticates and an authentication cookie is emitted and valid for the `foo.com` domain.
3. Now the user needs to go to `https://bar.com` and be automatically authenticated on this domain. On some page on `https://foo.com` you could create a form containing the value of the authentication cookie to be posted:

   ```
   <form action="https://bar.com" method="post">
       <input type="hidden" name="token" value="PUT THE VALUE OF THE AUTHENTICATION COOKIE HERE" />
       <button type="submit">Go to bar.com</button>
   </form>
   ```
4. The user submits the authentication cookie to the `bar.com`. The script that receives this form submission reads the authentication token value that was posted and uses the [`FormsAuthentication.Decrypt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.decrypt.aspx) method to decrypt the authentication ticket and read the user name. Since both applications on `foo.com` and `bar.com` use the same machine keys, the ticket that was encrypted on foo.com will be successfully decrypted by bar.com
5. The script at `bar.com` having extracted the authenticated username from the token, it emits a forms authentication cookie valid on `bar.com` using the [`FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.setauthcookie.aspx) method.
6. The user is now authenticated on `bar.com`

The whole security of this model relies on the fact that SSL is used when POSTing the forms authentication token from `foo.com` to `bar.com` so the token cannot be captured by a [man-in-the-middle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) and that both applications share the same machine keys for encrypting and decrypting those tokens.