# Unable to access cookie with JavaScript set by another application

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-chrome-extension, session-cookies, httpcookie

Developing Chrome Extension and linked it with the amazon.com, I log in the user from the chrome extension's popup, and setup the cookie their in the pop-up,

the problem is that:

1. Amazon's page, maintaining its own cookie and the pop-up of my own chrome's extension is maintaining its own cookie.
2. I want to use my own's chrome extension cookie values their in the Amazon's cookie so that I keep a track of that specific user's interaction with my Extension.

Note: I need javaScript code to access the cookie of one's application to another.

I read the following article but it is not exactly what I want:
[How to check if a cookie exists even if it was created in another application? (using JS or C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997715/how-to-check-if-a-cookie-exists-even-if-it-was-created-in-another-application)

Comment: I don't believe that's possible. It would be a security and privacy risk.

Comment: @Shmiddty: exactly the first thing that popped into my mind when I saw this question...........

Comment: See http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies.html, and get back when you're stuck.

Comment: That seems, what I am looking for. Let me try it. I'll inform you if it works or if I have any problems. I appreciate your help.